# Редактор и файловый менеджер в MODx

Tags: modx, php

При создании ресурса в MODx у меня создается папка с именем "id ресурса".

Вопрос: как сделать, что бы в текстовом редакторе, при выборе изображения, в открытом файловом менеджере открывалась не вся файловая система а исключительно папка с таким же именем как id ресурса ?

Просто если менеджеры начнут ставить картинки в текст, то они могут не только выбрать картинку, но и удалить половину файлов. Да и вообще так удобней было бы.

> Может есть у кого какой набросок похожего плагина ?

Answer (score 2):

Уточните редакцию MODx. EVO или REVO?

Хорошо, значит так смотрим:

```
    case 'OnRichTextBrowserInit':
...
            $source = $tiny->context->getOption('default_media_source',null,1);

            $modx->controller->addHtml('<script type="text/javascript">var inRevo20 = '.($inRevo20 ? 1 : 0).';MODx.source = "'.$source.'";</script>');
```

в другом файле

```
$tiny = new TinyMCE($modx,$scriptProperties);
```

Это говорит о том что при срабатывании OnRichTextBrowserInit мы ищем sources. И видим из кода что

```
$tiny->context->getOption === $modx->context->getOption
```

Получается смотрим что выдает а выдает оно 1 все правильно. Далее понимаем что здесь ловить нечего лезем в modmediasource.class.php и находим это чудо:

OnMediaSourceGetProperties

Вот оно событие в котором мжно переоределить путь. Создаем плагин на это событие и меняем basePath на свой.

И будет это как то так:

```
switch ($modx->event->name) {
    case 'OnMediaSourceGetProperties':
        $params=$modx->fromJson($scriptProperties['properties']);
        $params['basePath']['value']=$params['basePath']['value'].'**вашИД**/';
        $params['baseUrl']['value']=$params['baseUrl']['value'].'**вашИД**/';;
        $modx->event->output($modx->toJson($params));
        break; 
}
```

Comment: В общем если это Revo то читайте про "Источники файлов" и там все будет понятно как закрыть пользователя в определенной папке.

Comment: Да у меня Revo. То, что сменить источник файлов, это понятно, но я же не буду делать для каждого ресурса новый источник файлов.

Comment: TinyMCE использует источник файлов по умолчанию ( это определено в системных настройках, ключ default_media_source).
Отредактируйте права доступа пользователю или установите в системных настройках для всех.

Или для типов рессурсов распределяйте таким же образом.

Comment: К стати по поводу плагина он простой получается. OnFormRender и переопределяем настроечку медиаресурса точнее не всю а только путь к файлу.

Comment: Можно хотя бы строчку для понимания, о чем именно вы говорите, а то как то в двух словах не особо понятно.

Comment: Круто !!! Спасибо, сегодня попробую покопаться.

Comment: Такой метод не совсем хорош, я бы сказал, потому как он каждый раз дозаписывает в конец строку. Вообще вариант такой, пишем в basePath и baseUrl такой путь assets/images/$id, единственная проблема, остается как то узнать ID открытой страницы в админке.

Comment: так добавте еще какой-то параметр к примеру что уже изменено. Я не вижу проблемы вы отпраляете json массив и а на счет узнать ИД... 
Давате попробуем так;
Для редактирования получится как то так:
$sourceUpdateActionID = 0;
if ($object = $modx->getObject('modAction', array('namespace' => 'core', 'controller' => 'source/update', ))) {$sourceUpdateActionID = $object->get('id');}
думаю это даст $sourceUpdateActionID = 30
Ну а далее просто если мы знаем что $_REQUEST['a']==$sourceUpdateActionID ==30 в моем случаи то $_REQUEST['id'] можно свободно пользовать. А вот для создания ИД уже не угадаешь.